# Using Flex box with a set size div

Tags: html, css

I have a container at 100% width and an image in a left floating `<div>` at 100px X 100px with a right floating `<div>` at the same height but i want it to fill the remaining space without having to use a table structure. I believe i can do this with the css element Flex but does anyone know how?

#### CSS

```css
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
#image {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
#rightcontent {
    float:right;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="image">
    </div>
    <div id="rightcontent">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Comment: Flexbox is not very well supported yet, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **CSS `display:flex;`** property to the parent element;

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eQUMabU/8/edit)

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    display: flex; /* NOTE THIS */
    overflow:auto;
}
#image {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#faf;
}
#rightcontent {
    background:#cf5;
    width:100%;      /* AND THIS */
}
```

---

You don't need to use `<table>` to **emulate a `table` behavior**:

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eQUMabU/4/edit)

```
#container{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  display:table;  /* NOTE THIS */
}
#container > div{
  display:table-cell; /* AND THIS */
}
#image{
  width:100px;
  background:#faf;
}
#rightcontent{
  background:#cf5;
}
```

---

Or by simply assigning the **background to the parent**:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eQUMabU/7/edit)**

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:#cf5;  /* NOTE THIS */
}
#image {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background:#faf;
}
#rightcontent {

}
```

Comment: +1 for `display: table-cell;`, about as clean solution as you can get.

Comment: @xec thanks, added most of the possible and nicest solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add an overflow to your right element without floating it:

```
#rightcontent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will make `#rightcontent` to fill the remaining space. Value could be also `scroll`, but it really doesn't matter because there is nothing to overflow.

It's the cleanest solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/SW8uE/

Comment: @theDazzler It does work. Who downvoted this? Also, a good read: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

Comment: I didn't downvote it because it is close to the solution. You need to add a 100px height to right div

Comment: I think the question is to fill the remaining horizontal space.

Comment: he says he wants a right div of same height "<div> at 100px X 100px with a right floating <div> at the same height "